# Lucky Number App keeps garnering same numbers

Tags: android

I'm using Android Studio, I'm trying to create an app that will generate 4 numbers between 1 to 30.  As you can see by the image below it keeps genering the same numnber 4 times which is not great. I am posting all the code I design to give you a good idea of the way I coded the program.  Any help would by greatly appreciated

```
package com.webbrewery.luckyapp;

import static android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class LuckyNumberActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView welcomeTxt, luckyNumberTxt, luckyNumberTxt1, luckNumberTxt2, luckyNumberTxt3;
    Button share_btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lucky_number);

        welcomeTxt = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        luckyNumberTxt = findViewById(R.id.lucky_number_txt);
        luckyNumberTxt1 = findViewById(R.id.lucky_number_txt1);
        luckNumberTxt2 = findViewById(R.id.lucky_number_txt2);
        luckyNumberTxt3 = findViewById(R.id.lucky_number_txt3);
        share_btn = findViewById(R.id.share_number_btn);

        // Username
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String userName = i.getStringExtra("name");

        // Random Number Generatedd
        int random_Num = generateRandomNumber();

        luckyNumberTxt.setText(" " +random_Num);
        luckyNumberTxt1.setText(" " +random_Num);
        luckNumberTxt2.setText(" " +random_Num);
        luckyNumberTxt3.setText(" " +random_Num);


        // When Share is Clickes
        share_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                shareData(userName, random_Num);
            }

        });

    }

    // Method
    public int generateRandomNumber() {

        Random random = new Random();
        int upper_limit = 30;
        int randomNumberGenerated = random.nextInt(upper_limit);
        return randomNumberGenerated;
    }

    // Method to share data, Gmail, WhatsApp.....
    public void shareData(String username, int randomNum){

        // Implict Intent
        Intent i = new Intent(ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/plain");

        // Convert the int to string
        String number = String.valueOf(randomNum);

        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, username + " Get Lucky Today! ");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your Lucky Numbers are: " + number);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose A Platform"));

    }
}
```

}[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are currently just generating one random number. You have to generate a random number for all your text field separately.

Like this:

```
luckyNumberTxt.setText(" " + generateRandomNumber());
luckyNumberTxt1.setText(" " + generateRandomNumber());
luckNumberTxt2.setText(" " + generateRandomNumber());
luckyNumberTxt3.setText(" " + generateRandomNumber());
```

Or just create 4 separate int variables:

```
int random_Num1 = generateRandomNumber();
int random_Num2 = generateRandomNumber();
int random_Num3 = generateRandomNumber();
int random_Num4 = generateRandomNumber();

luckyNumberTxt.setText(" " + random_Num1);
luckyNumberTxt1.setText(" " + random_Num2);
luckNumberTxt2.setText(" " + random_Num3);
luckyNumberTxt3.setText(" " + random_Num4);
```

You can also leave out the empty String if you use "String.valueOf()":

```
luckyNumberTxt.setText(String.valueOf(generateRandomNumber()));
luckyNumberTxt1.setText(String.valueOf(generateRandomNumber()));
luckNumberTxt2.setText(String.valueOf(generateRandomNumber()));
luckyNumberTxt3.setText(String.valueOf(generateRandomNumber()));
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you very much it's working right now.  I decided to use your first option.